# Lenovo Thinkpad T590 weird Bluetooth behavior

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth

I recently got the T590 and I am running 18.04 since but I am getting some connection drops when using my bluetooth bose qc 35 II headphones.
Connection is still shown as active and connected, but media volumes completely gets silenced. The way to fix it is turn off and on bluetooth.

It's really random, it works some times for hours, but some others drops after a few minutes. Tried the same headphones with T580, they work perfectly.

Tried also to reinstall bluetooth ubuntu drivers altogether but same result.

Any idea?

EDIT:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:56a6 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What are you calling "bluetooth ubuntu drivers"? The only really good solution is to use 5GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 2.4 GHz wifi and bluetooth share the same frequency.

You can try to fix it by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-btfix.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

Reboot to apply.

Comment: hmm but why I don't have this problem with T580? I also connect with 2.4GHz networks there.

Comment: You may have a different wireless adapter there. Some work better with bluetooth.